# Strange CSS behavior in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I would be most grateful if someone could tell me why the title bars in this WordPress theme don't work in Firefox.

If you scroll down a bit, and check out the heading 'Recent Works'. On Chrome IE, etc, the bar starts left, then breaks for the title, and continues the rest of the wrapper width. In Firefox, the title bar does not show left of the title, and only begins after the title.

Please check out the theme here: http://mcstudiosmx.com/demo/wp/hi-wordpress/

Lazy developer has not released a fix for this and I cannot find a workaround. Any help/suggestions would be awesome :)

Comment: be some more "code specific" when asking on stackoverflow. Show us relevant code fragments to work on and reduce external links.

Comment: For what it's worth, the Firefox behavior here is closer to what the spec calls for, insofar as the spec defines the behavior at all....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding the left property to the following:

```
block-title .stripe {
background: transparent url(images/template/stripe.png) repeat-x right center;
display: inline-block;
height: 21px;
margin: 4px 17px 0 0;
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
left:0;
}
```

Comment: `position:absolute` and `float:right` makes absolutely no sense. Either float or position...

Comment: @Christoph You are right.  I was lazy at the time of posting this and simply copied the block css related to the selector in question and added the `left` property.  I have removed the `float` property so that it may more clearly help someone in the future.